# How to show multiple posts of a same category?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I want to show multiple posts of a same category, but I want to print category name only once.The posts having same category will be printed alongside under once printed category name.
Below is the picture of output that I want:[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php 
                            $args = array('post_type' => 'books_section', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
                            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                            while ($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">
                            <div class="img-category w-75">
                                <?php 
                                $category = get_the_category(); 

                                if($category[0]){

                                    $thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

                                    echo "<img height='50' width='100' alt='' src='$thumbnail'>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <!-- <img height="50" width="100" alt="" src="<?php the_field('category_image'); ?>"> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-11 col-xl-11">
                            <h5 class="text-capitalize">
                                <?php
                                    $category = get_the_category();
                                    echo $category[0]->cat_name;
                                ?>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mt-5">
                            <a class="text-decoration-none" href="<?php the_field('amazon_book_link');?>" target="">
                                <div class="book-hover">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                                    <!-- <img alt="" src="./assets/images/Layer 40@1X.png" class="" height="350" width="250"> -->
                                </div>
                                <h6 class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold text-center mt-2 book-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h6>
                                <?php if( get_field('audio_book') == 'yes' ): ?>
                                    <h6 class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold text-center mt-2 book-type">Audio Book</h6>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if( get_field('comng_soon') == 'yes'): ?>
                                    <h6 class="text-capitalize font-weight-bold text-center mt-2 book-type">Coming Soon</h6>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

And this is result that I am getting: [image]

What I am getting result now is that loop is printing all posts along with their category name separately, But I need category name only once and the print all the posts of that particular category.
And then loop should print other posts of the new category.
Help me please.

Comment: I am using custom post type for this books section.

Comment: Create a variable before the loop with a start value of -1; inside loop compare category with that variable if it's not equal, show category name and update the variable, so the name will show until next category.

Comment: @Triby Can you do that for me? Because I tried, but didn't make it happen.

Comment: I don't know `$category` values, please try it and edit the question to include you're attempt, I'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who devoted my answer, it was not an easy task for me specially as a beginner. So I experimented and found a way to figure it out. Here is the code which is working perfectly.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
               'orderby' => 'name',
               'hide_empty'=> true,
                 );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
?>
<h5><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h5>
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'books_section', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => $cat->name);
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()): $the_query -> the_post();   
?>
//Rest of the HTML goes here to style books
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php 
   }
?>
```

What I did in this code is, first I started a foreach loop to get all the categories one by one, then in this loop (nested loop) got all my posts in a while loop by additionally adding a category name parameter so only those posts will be fetched which have the above category name which is generated by foreach loop. So when the first time the outer loop gets a category it will move inside the while loop and will get all the posts related to the category and then leave the inner loop. The process goes again and again, and by finally I got all my posts according to their categories.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789905/3567724) answers exactly what you asked.

In the example he puts a limit of 5 posts, you can set it to -1 for unlimited posts.

Additionally, if you want to hide the categories that don't have any post just add this to the $args of get_categories():

```
'hide_empty' => true
```

Hope this helps!

Note: if you use a custom post for movies, you should also create a custom taxonomy instead of using the default categories. Use categories only if you are completely sure that you are never going to use them for normal articles.